# Parsing Complex Json with Gson Java - Only nodes

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have this Json structure and I need to get the information for "myId", "name", "adress1" and "city".

```
      {
        "InformationResponse":{
        "Id":"122212",
        "customerSessionId":"007",
        "Summary":{
        "myId":1234567,
        "name":"Casino",
        "address1":"13 Street",
        "city":"Las Vegas",
       },
...
```

I am using Gson (Java).
I created 3 Class (InformationResponse, Summary and Main)

```
public class Summary {

    private String myId;
    private String name;
    private String city;

    public String getMyId() {
        return myId;
    }
    public void setMyId(String myId) {
        this.myId= myId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getMyId() + ", "+getName()+", "+getCity();
    }
}
```

MyObject.class

```
public class MyObject{

    private Summary summary;

    public Summary getSummary() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        sb.append("Summary="+getSummary()+"\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

In the Main I can see my Json file and I am doing this:

```
// Get Gson object
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

// parse json string to object
MyObject myobject1 = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

But I have null everytime.

Thanks for your help!

Jean M.

Comment: Looks like you might have a class cast problem from MyObject to Hotel.

Comment: thanks but actually I did a mistake when I copy/paste. It is MyObject in my code. Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This          @SerializedName("Id")
               private String myId;

Answer (score -2):

Gson requires a default no args constructor:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

Try adding a public no-args constructor to both your Summary and MyObject classes.

```
public Summary() {}
public MyObject() {}
```

Comment: From the docs: "While deserializing an Object, Gson needs to create a default instance of the class
Well-behaved  classes that are meant for serialization and deserialization should have a no-argument constructor"

Comment: I think its great that you read the docs, I do. But a) the docs are outdated b) again, gson doesn't require an explicit no-arg constructor. And c) this wasn't the op's problem because of that. The only time you would need to explicitly add a nullary constructor is if you had a class will a non-nullary constructor, preventing gson from calling `newInstance()` to instantiate the class via reflection